# Using shove to add a string to an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, module, include, require

As part of an online Ruby tutorial, I must create a text-based game. One requirement is that I use `require` to pull in another file. I've done that as well as `include` the module that holds a method. However, I cannot produce the result I want. Here's my file with the module:

```
module Inventory

  def Inventory.inventory(item)

    items = Array.new

    if item == "show"
      items.inspect
    else
      items << item
    end
  end

end
```

I want the parameter `(item)` to be added to the array `items` as a string that can be `inspected` when I pass the `"show"` argument to it.

So for example, I want to add a 'bat' to the inventory so I call `Inventory.inventory("bat")`.   Later I'd like to add other things. But when I call `Inventory.inventory("show")` it doesn't show anything.

I've spent days looking through many other tutorials and hundreds of questions here but still can't get it work. I'm probably not understanding something really fundamental so please be gracious to me as I'm still learning.

Is it the way I'm adding to an array? The way I'm trying to get it to show? Or do I not understand how to use methods and arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can Dylan's answer if you want to go with instance approach or you can use class variables.

The problem with your code is that you initialize `items` local variable every time you call `inventory`.

Here is a version that will persist items in a class variable:

```
module Inventory

  def Inventory.inventory(item)

    @@items ||= Array.new

    if item == "show"
      @@items.inspect
    else
      @@items << item
    end
  end

end

Inventory.inventory 1
Inventory.inventory 2
p Inventory.inventory 'show'
```

this is producing

```
"[1, 2]"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. There's still a few things I don't understand: why do I need to "p" or print Inventory.inventory("show")? Why doesn't it work with out having to print it?

Comment: And why did you use the conditional assignment operator (||=)? As I understand it, this operator assigns value to a variable if the variable hasn't yet been assigned. But is an empty array ([]) not considered a value?

Comment: `||=` is a nil guard. it will initialize `@@items` only if it is nil. `p`, `print`, `puts` is for sending stuff to stdout.

Comment: I understand p/print/puts but I thought that the .inspect method automatically prints stuff out. Learning something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

This would make a lot more sense as a class. This way, you can store the items in an instance variable that will persist during multiple calls to `add`, `show`, etc. You can of course put this class into a separate file and still include it.

```
class Inventory
  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def add(item)
    @items << item
  end

  def show
    @items.inspect
  end
end

# To use the class:
inventory = Inventory.new
inventory.add('bat')
inventory.show
# => ["bat"]
```

Comment: It appears I don't understand classes and instance variables as well as I thought. Part of my exercise was to create classes so how to I get this Inventory class to work within other classes? Do I use inheritance? I was told to avoid meta-programming at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your items array is being recreated every time this method is called, so there is no persistence between method calls for what is passed into the array. Dylan Markow's answer shows how you can use instance variables to persist values between method calls.